# Awk split file give incomplete lines

Tags: linux, csv, awk, gawk

My file is a `csv` file with comma delimited fields.

I tried to split the file into multiple files by first field. I did the following:

```
cat myfile.csv | awk -F',' '{print $0 > "Mydata"$1".csv"}'
```

It does split the file, but the file is corrupted, the last line of each file is not complete. The breaking position seems random. Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: can you show your input csv  or at least the part in question (the end)?

Comment: What version of awk / what OS?  Also, can you post the input file?

Comment: played with it, worked for me. Please show the input file...

Comment: I use a Linux machine. sorry guys, thanks for the help, I cannot seem to reproduce the problem. On my machine, I don't use cat to product the stream,  so instead of the cat file | etc, I used mylisenertolog | etc. I am pretty sure the mylisenertolog program produce full lines because I also have mylisenertolog >> alllog.csv in another console and that file is fine.

Answer (score 1):

These types of problem are invariably because you created your input file on Windows and so it has spurious control-Ms at the end of the lines. Run dos2unix on your input file to clean it up then re-run your awk command but re-write it as:

```
awk -F',' '{print > ("Mydata" $1 ".csv") }' myfile.csv
```

to solve a couple of unrelated problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use this awk command to ignore `\r` characters before `\n`:

```
awk -F ',' -v RS='\r\n' '{print > ("Mydata" $1 ".csv") }' myfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't forget to close your files :

```
awk -F ',' '{ f="Mydata"$1".csv"; print $0 > f; close(f) }' myfile.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a real CSV parser/generator instead. It's safe for unusual inputs including those with multi-lined values. And here's a one-liner for Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'require "csv";CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift){|r| File.open("Mydata#{r[0]}.csv","w").puts(CSV.generate_line(r))}' file.csv
```